# How do I deal with website redirections when writing Selenium Scripts

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-testing

I am testing that a web application is working as it is supposed to:

here is my script

```
setSpeed    7000    
open    router2/default.aspx?FIRID=10CAAR&SUMSTAT=1&SID=200ba6db-99d7-474b-a26b-8a0b9e772fec&PID=   
click   name=radio_43   
clickAndWait    id=ctl00_Content_btnContinue    
verifyTextPresent   United States Military  
selectWindow    null
```

I am using the setSpeed command because of that link shown below it ( router2/default.aspx?FIRID=10CAAR.... )  , which gets redirected took quickly and then generates a random URL(so I can't grab that URL).

That's why I put the 7 second delay. but it seems slow/inefficient.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to slow down the speed of execution just put `pause` for few seconds if required.

use getAttribute method i.e. `storeAttribute` in IDE to get the url you want to open.

when you use the open command selenium waits for the timeout period.

Thnaks.